# Normalize transactions data from time and status columns to minutes per status value

Tags: sql, oracle, normalization

I have a table of changes in user statuses such as:

```
insert_time     status
1/1/2017 0:00   AVAILABLE
1/1/2017 0:15   BUSY
1/1/2017 0:30   NOT AVAILABLE
1/1/2017 1:30   AVAILABLE
1/1/2017 3:10   BUSY
1/1/2017 5:00   NOT AVAILABLE
```

For example: this user was available between 00:00 and 00:15 and busy from 00:15 to 00:30 and so on.

In order to analyze the data I need to transform it to this structure:

```
day       hour  available minutes   not available minutes   busy minutes
1/1/2017     0                 15                      30             15
1/1/2017     1                 30                      30              0
1/1/2017     2                 60                       0              0
1/1/2017     3                 10                       0             50
1/1/2017     4                  0                       0             60
```

whhich includes data for hours that status has not been changed.

I think it's not a simple PIVOT query, because I need to break single row into several columns including hours with no data.

How can I do it in an Oracle SQL query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL Developer: How to transpose rows to columns using PIVOT function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945504/oracle-sql-developer-how-to-transpose-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-function)

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this kind of query involves two pieces: category-generation followed by aggregation into the generated categories.

For the data you provided, the first step in this kind of solution is to bucket the data by hour (since the data you provided doesn't have any events in the 02:00 hour or the 04:00 hour, to show these hours in the final result, they can be *generated* instead).

The second piece is to aggregate into the per-hour buckets via a `pivot`, as mentioned by Jorge Campos in the comments.

Below is an example.

First create a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE INSERT_TIME_STATUS(
  INSERT_TIME TIMESTAMP,
  STATUS VARCHAR2(128)
);
```

And add the test data:

```
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'AVAILABLE');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:15:00', 'BUSY');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:30:00', 'NOT AVAILABLE');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 01:30:00', 'AVAILABLE');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 03:10:00', 'BUSY');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 05:00:00', 'NOT AVAILABLE');
```

Then create the query.  This will use subquery factoring to outline the two-step nature of this process.

The `CALENDAR` subfactor here will generate each hour of the day, regardless of whether any records occurred during that hour.

The `HOUR_CALENDAR` subfactor will assign each provided status-record to a specific hour, and  will chop statuses that cross into another hour into pieces, so all records fit within a one hour-span.

The `DURATION_IN_STATUS` subfactor will count how many minutes each status was active during each hour.

The final query will `PIVOT` to aggregate (`SUM`) the amount of time each `STATUS` was active during each hour.

```
WITH HOUR_OF_DAY AS (SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS THE_HOUR
                     FROM DUAL
                     CONNECT BY LEVEL < 25),
    CALENDAR AS (SELECT DAY_START
                 FROM (
                   SELECT (TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:00:00' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(DATE_INCREMENT.OFFSET, 'DAY')) AS DAY_START
                   FROM (SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS OFFSET
                         FROM DUAL
                         CONNECT BY LEVEL < 9999) DATE_INCREMENT)
                 WHERE DAY_START BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(TRUNC(INSERT_TIME_STATUS.INSERT_TIME))
                                          FROM INSERT_TIME_STATUS)
                 AND (SELECT MAX(TRUNC(INSERT_TIME_STATUS.INSERT_TIME))
                      FROM INSERT_TIME_STATUS)),
    HOUR_CALENDAR AS (
     SELECT
       TO_CHAR(CALENDAR.DAY_START, 'MM/DD/YYYY')                                               AS THE_DAY,
       HOUR_OF_DAY.THE_HOUR,
       CALENDAR.DAY_START + NUMTODSINTERVAL(HOUR_OF_DAY.THE_HOUR, 'HOUR')                      AS HOUR_START,
       (SELECT MAX(INSERT_TIME_STATUS.STATUS)
       KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST
         ORDER BY INSERT_TIME_STATUS.INSERT_TIME ASC)
        FROM INSERT_TIME_STATUS
        WHERE INSERT_TIME_STATUS.INSERT_TIME <= DAY_START + NUMTODSINTERVAL(THE_HOUR, 'HOUR')) AS HOUR_START_STATUS
     FROM CALENDAR
       CROSS JOIN HOUR_OF_DAY),
    ALL_HOUR_STATUS AS (
    SELECT
      HOUR_CALENDAR.THE_DAY,
      HOUR_CALENDAR.THE_HOUR,
      HOUR_CALENDAR.HOUR_START        AS THE_TIME,
      HOUR_CALENDAR.HOUR_START_STATUS AS THE_STATUS
    FROM HOUR_CALENDAR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      HOUR_CALENDAR.THE_DAY,
      HOUR_CALENDAR.THE_HOUR,
      INSERT_TIME_STATUS.INSERT_TIME AS THE_TIME,
      INSERT_TIME_STATUS.STATUS      AS THE_STATUS
    FROM HOUR_CALENDAR
      INNER JOIN INSERT_TIME_STATUS
        ON HOUR_CALENDAR.HOUR_START < INSERT_TIME_STATUS.INSERT_TIME
           AND HOUR_CALENDAR.THE_HOUR = EXTRACT(HOUR FROM INSERT_TIME_STATUS.INSERT_TIME)),
    DURATION_IN_STATUS AS (
     SELECT
       ALL_HOUR_STATUS.THE_DAY,
       ALL_HOUR_STATUS.THE_HOUR,
       ALL_HOUR_STATUS.THE_STATUS,
       (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM
                (COALESCE(LEAD(THE_TIME)
                          OVER (
                            PARTITION BY NULL
                            ORDER BY THE_TIME ASC ), TO_TIMESTAMP(THE_DAY, 'MM/DD/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(THE_HOUR + 1, 'HOUR')) - THE_TIME)) * 60)
       +
       EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM
               (COALESCE(LEAD(THE_TIME)
                         OVER (
                           PARTITION BY NULL
                           ORDER BY THE_TIME ASC ), TO_TIMESTAMP(THE_DAY, 'MM/DD/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(THE_HOUR + 1, 'HOUR')) - THE_TIME))
         AS DURATION_IN_STATUS
     FROM ALL_HOUR_STATUS)
SELECT
  THE_DAY,
  THE_HOUR,
  COALESCE(AVAILABLE, 0)     AS AVAILABLE,
  COALESCE(NOT_AVAILABLE, 0) AS NOT_AVAILABLE,
  COALESCE(BUSY, 0)          AS BUSY
FROM DURATION_IN_STATUS
PIVOT (SUM(DURATION_IN_STATUS)
  FOR THE_STATUS
  IN ('AVAILABLE' AS AVAILABLE, 'NOT AVAILABLE' AS NOT_AVAILABLE, 'BUSY' AS BUSY)
)
ORDER BY THE_DAY ASC, THE_HOUR ASC;
```

Result:

```
THE_DAY     THE_HOUR  AVAILABLE  NOT_AVAILABLE  BUSY  
01/01/2017  0         15         30             15    
01/01/2017  1         30         30             0     
01/01/2017  2         60         0              0     
01/01/2017  3         10         0              50    
01/01/2017  4         0          0              60    
01/01/2017  5         0          60             0     
01/01/2017  6         0          60             0     
01/01/2017  7         0          60             0     
01/01/2017  8         0          60             0     
01/01/2017  9         0          60             0     
01/01/2017  10        0          60             0     
01/01/2017  11        0          60             0     
01/01/2017  12        0          60             0     
01/01/2017  13        0          60             0     
01/01/2017  14        0          60             0     
01/01/2017  15        0          60             0     
01/01/2017  16        0          60             0     
01/01/2017  17        0          60             0     
01/01/2017  18        0          60             0     
01/01/2017  19        0          60             0     
01/01/2017  20        0          60             0     
01/01/2017  21        0          60             0     
01/01/2017  22        0          60             0     
01/01/2017  23        0          60             0     


24 rows selected.
```

This example query generates records for the entire day.  So the last status of `NOT AVAILABLE` carries through.  If you want to stop at the time of the last-assigned status, this behavior could be adjusted as needed.

**EDIT, in response to your update to evaluate these times per  `channel_id` and `user_id`, here is another example:**

First create the test table:

```
CREATE TABLE INSERT_TIME_STATUS(
  USER_ID NUMBER,
  CHANNEL_ID NUMBER,
  INSERT_TIME TIMESTAMP,
  STATUS VARCHAR2(128)
);
```

And load it (here user_id=1 is on channels 3 and 4 and user_id=2 is on chanel 3 only) :

```
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (1111,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 0:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'AVAILABLE');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (1111,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 0:15','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'BUSY');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (1111,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 0:30','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'NOT AVAILABLE');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (1111,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 1:30','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'AVAILABLE');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (1111,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 3:10','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'BUSY');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (1111,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 5:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'NOT AVAILABLE');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (1111,4,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 0:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'AVAILABLE');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (1111,4,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 0:15','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'BUSY');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (1111,4,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 0:30','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'NOT AVAILABLE');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (1111,4,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 1:30','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'AVAILABLE');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (1111,4,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 3:10','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'BUSY');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (1111,4,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 5:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'NOT AVAILABLE');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (2222,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 0:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'AVAILABLE');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (2222,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 0:15','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'BUSY');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (2222,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 0:30','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'NOT AVAILABLE');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (2222,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 1:30','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'AVAILABLE');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (2222,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 3:10','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'BUSY');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (2222,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 5:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'NOT AVAILABLE');
INSERT INTO INSERT_TIME_STATUS VALUES (2222,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('1/1/2017 5:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),'NOT AVAILABLE');
```

Then update the query to generate data per-`user_id` per-`channel_id`.  In this example, data is included for all time, for all channels each user is involved with.  user 1 will have counts for each hour of the day for channels `3` and `4` while user-2 will have counts for each hour of the day for channel 3 only  (if it had records on another channel, that channel be included as well).

```
WITH HOUR_OF_DAY AS (SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS THE_HOUR
                     FROM DUAL
                     CONNECT BY LEVEL < 25),
    CALENDAR AS (SELECT DAY_START
                 FROM (
                   SELECT ((SELECT MIN(TRUNC(INSERT_TIME_STATUS.INSERT_TIME))
                            FROM INSERT_TIME_STATUS) + NUMTODSINTERVAL(DATE_INCREMENT.OFFSET, 'DAY')) AS DAY_START
                   FROM (SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS OFFSET
                         FROM DUAL
                         CONNECT BY LEVEL < 9999) DATE_INCREMENT)
                 WHERE DAY_START BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(TRUNC(INSERT_TIME_STATUS.INSERT_TIME))
                                          FROM INSERT_TIME_STATUS)
                 AND (SELECT MAX(TRUNC(INSERT_TIME_STATUS.INSERT_TIME))
                      FROM INSERT_TIME_STATUS)),
    USER_CHANNEL_HOUR_CALENDAR AS (
     SELECT
       USER_ID,
       CHANNEL_ID,
       CALENDAR.DAY_START,
       TO_CHAR(CALENDAR.DAY_START, 'MM/DD/YYYY')                                               AS THE_DAY,
       HOUR_OF_DAY.THE_HOUR,
       CALENDAR.DAY_START + NUMTODSINTERVAL(HOUR_OF_DAY.THE_HOUR, 'HOUR')                      AS HOUR_START
     FROM CALENDAR
       CROSS JOIN HOUR_OF_DAY
       --
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT UNIQUE USER_ID, CHANNEL_ID FROM INSERT_TIME_STATUS)
  ),
    HOUR_CALENDAR AS (
     SELECT USER_ID,
       CHANNEL_ID,
       THE_DAY,
       THE_HOUR,
       DAY_START,
       HOUR_START,
       (SELECT MAX(INSERT_TIME_STATUS.STATUS)
       KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST
         ORDER BY INSERT_TIME_STATUS.INSERT_TIME ASC)
        FROM INSERT_TIME_STATUS
        WHERE INSERT_TIME_STATUS.INSERT_TIME <= DAY_START + NUMTODSINTERVAL(THE_HOUR, 'HOUR')
              AND INSERT_TIME_STATUS.USER_ID = USER_ID
              AND INSERT_TIME_STATUS.CHANNEL_ID = CHANNEL_ID) AS HOUR_START_STATUS
     FROM USER_CHANNEL_HOUR_CALENDAR),
    ALL_HOUR_STATUS AS (
    SELECT
      HOUR_CALENDAR.USER_ID,
      HOUR_CALENDAR.CHANNEL_ID,
      HOUR_CALENDAR.THE_DAY,
      HOUR_CALENDAR.THE_HOUR,
      HOUR_CALENDAR.HOUR_START        AS THE_TIME,
      HOUR_CALENDAR.HOUR_START_STATUS AS THE_STATUS
    FROM HOUR_CALENDAR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      INSERT_TIME_STATUS.USER_ID,
      INSERT_TIME_STATUS.CHANNEL_ID,
      HOUR_CALENDAR.THE_DAY,
      HOUR_CALENDAR.THE_HOUR,
      INSERT_TIME_STATUS.INSERT_TIME AS THE_TIME,
      INSERT_TIME_STATUS.STATUS      AS THE_STATUS
    FROM HOUR_CALENDAR
      INNER JOIN INSERT_TIME_STATUS
        ON HOUR_CALENDAR.HOUR_START < INSERT_TIME_STATUS.INSERT_TIME
           AND HOUR_CALENDAR.THE_HOUR = EXTRACT(HOUR FROM INSERT_TIME_STATUS.INSERT_TIME)
           AND HOUR_CALENDAR.USER_ID = INSERT_TIME_STATUS.USER_ID
           AND HOUR_CALENDAR.CHANNEL_ID = INSERT_TIME_STATUS.CHANNEL_ID),
    DURATION_IN_STATUS AS (
     SELECT
       ALL_HOUR_STATUS.USER_ID,
       ALL_HOUR_STATUS.CHANNEL_ID,
       ALL_HOUR_STATUS.THE_DAY,
       ALL_HOUR_STATUS.THE_HOUR,
       ALL_HOUR_STATUS.THE_STATUS,
       (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM
                (COALESCE(LEAD(THE_TIME)
                          OVER (
                            PARTITION BY USER_ID, CHANNEL_ID
                            ORDER BY THE_TIME ASC ), TO_TIMESTAMP(THE_DAY, 'MM/DD/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(THE_HOUR + 1, 'HOUR')) - THE_TIME)) * 60)
       +
       EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM
               (COALESCE(LEAD(THE_TIME)
                         OVER (
                           PARTITION BY USER_ID, CHANNEL_ID
                           ORDER BY THE_TIME ASC ), TO_TIMESTAMP(THE_DAY, 'MM/DD/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(THE_HOUR + 1, 'HOUR')) - THE_TIME))
         AS DURATION_IN_STATUS
     FROM ALL_HOUR_STATUS)
SELECT
  USER_ID,
  CHANNEL_ID,
  THE_DAY,
  THE_HOUR,
  COALESCE(AVAILABLE, 0)     AS AVAILABLE,
  COALESCE(NOT_AVAILABLE, 0) AS NOT_AVAILABLE,
  COALESCE(BUSY, 0)          AS BUSY
FROM DURATION_IN_STATUS
PIVOT (SUM(DURATION_IN_STATUS)
  FOR THE_STATUS
  IN ('AVAILABLE' AS AVAILABLE, 'NOT AVAILABLE' AS NOT_AVAILABLE, 'BUSY' AS BUSY)
)
  -- You can additionally filter the result
  -- WHERE CHANNEL_ID IN (3,4)
  -- WHERE USER_ID = 12345
  -- WHERE THE_DAY > TO_CHAR(DATE '2017-01-01')
  -- etc.
ORDER BY USER_ID ASC, CHANNEL_ID ASC, THE_DAY ASC, THE_HOUR ASC;
```

Then test it:

```
USER_ID  CHANNEL_ID  THE_DAY     THE_HOUR  AVAILABLE  NOT_AVAILABLE  BUSY  
1111     3           01/01/2017  0         15         30             15    
1111     3           01/01/2017  1         30         30             0     
1111     3           01/01/2017  2         60         0              0     
1111     3           01/01/2017  3         10         0              50    
1111     3           01/01/2017  4         0          0              60    
1111     3           01/01/2017  5         0          60             0     
1111     3           01/01/2017  6         0          60             0  
...
1111     3           01/01/2017  23        0          60             0     
1111     4           01/01/2017  0         15         30             15    
1111     4           01/01/2017  1         30         30             0     
1111     4           01/01/2017  2         60         0              0     
1111     4           01/01/2017  3         10         0              50    
1111     4           01/01/2017  4         0          0              60    
1111     4           01/01/2017  5         0          60             0     
1111     4           01/01/2017  6         0          60             0
...
1111     4           01/01/2017  23        0          60             0     
2222     3           01/01/2017  0         15         30             15    
2222     3           01/01/2017  1         30         30             0     
2222     3           01/01/2017  2         60         0              0     
2222     3           01/01/2017  3         10         0              50    
2222     3           01/01/2017  4         0          0              60    
2222     3           01/01/2017  5         0          60             0     
2222     3           01/01/2017  6         0          60             0
```

Comment: It's a great solution.  I tried to add 2 more columns to this table, but I got stuck with the syntax.

Comment: It's a great solution.  I tried to add 2 more columns to this table, but I got stuck with the syntax.  
It looks the same, but per user_id and channel_id.  f.e:

user_id channel_id insert_time status
1111 3 1/1/2017 0:00 AVAILABLE
1111 3 1/1/2017 0:15 BUSY
1111 3 1/1/2017 0:30 NOT AVIALABLE
1111 3 1/1/2017 1:30 AVIALABLE
1111 4 1/1/2017 0:00 AVAILABLE
1111 4 1/1/2017 0:15 BUSY
1111 4 1/1/2017 0:30 NOT AVIALABLE
1111 4 1/1/2017 1:30 AVIALABLE
2222 3 1/1/2017 0:00 AVAILABLE
2222 3 1/1/2017 0:15 BUSY
2222 3 1/1/2017 0:30 NOT AVIALABLE
2222 3 1/1/2017 1:30 AVIALABLE

Comment: I want the summary result table to look like this:

user_id channel_id day hour available minutes not available minutes busy minutes
1111 3 1/1/2017 0 15 30 15
1111 3 1/1/2017 1 30 30 0
1111 3 1/1/2017 2 60 0 0
1111 3 1/1/2017 3 10 0 50
1111 4 1/1/2017 0 15 30 15
1111 4 1/1/2017 1 30 30 0
1111 4 1/1/2017 2 60 0 0
1111 4 1/1/2017 3 10 0 50
2222 3 1/1/2017 0 15 30 15
2222 3 1/1/2017 1 30 30 0
2222 3 1/1/2017 2 60 0 0
2222 3 1/1/2017 3 10 0 50

I tried to add it, but I got confused.
Can you please help me with adding this data ?

Thanks,
E

Comment: Thanks @user4810167 I don't see a `user_id` or `channel_id` anywhere in the data from your post.  Without seeing where these data came from, I don't know how to evaluate them.  If the current question has been answered, perhaps it may help things move forward to accept an answer here and ask a new question focused on the problem that occurs when adding the other `user_id` and `channel_id` columns to the table.  Thanks

Comment: I've opened a new question, I would appreciate if you can take a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996771/pivot-transactions-data-into-analytical-form-oracle-sql
Thanks !

Comment: Thanks @user4810167 Sure thing, I'll check it out and see what is going on.

Comment: @user4810167 ah that is closed as a duplicate.  I wonder what problem you encountered, or what exception you received--I'd been under the impression you had a new problem with `user_id` and `channel_id`.  Anyway I'll take a min and see if I can piece-together the goals.

Comment: @user4810167 Ok I think I see what you want to accomplish.  Though I don't know exactly what problem you encounttered with `user_id`, I'll update with something that I hope may help.

Comment: @user4810167  Ok I added another example at the end of my post, with times per `user_id` and `channel_id` .  Does this answer your question?  Thanks