# pivot transactions data into analytical form - Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot, normalization

I have a table of changes in user status per different channels, like following:

```
user_id   channel_id   insert_time     status
1111       3           1/1/2017 0:00   AVAILABLE
1111       3           1/1/2017 0:15   BUSY
1111       3           1/1/2017 0:30   NOT AVIALABLE
1111       3           1/1/2017 1:30   AVIALABLE
1111       3           1/1/2017 3:10   BUSY
1111       3           1/1/2017 5:00   NOT AVIALABLE
1111       4           1/1/2017 0:00   AVAILABLE
1111       4           1/1/2017 0:15   BUSY
1111       4           1/1/2017 0:30   NOT AVIALABLE
1111       4           1/1/2017 1:30   AVIALABLE
1111       4           1/1/2017 3:10   BUSY
1111       4           1/1/2017 5:00   NOT AVIALABLE
2222       3           1/1/2017 0:00   AVAILABLE
2222       3           1/1/2017 0:15   BUSY
2222       3           1/1/2017 0:30   NOT AVIALABLE
2222       3           1/1/2017 1:30   AVIALABLE
2222       3           1/1/2017 3:10   BUSY
2222       3           1/1/2017 5:00   NOT AVIALABLE
```

For example: user 1111 was available in channel 3 between 00:00 and 00:15 and busy from 00:15 to 00:30 and so on.

In order to analyze the data I need to transform it to this structure:

```
user_id   channel_id   day   hour   available minutes   not available minutes   busy minutes
1111   3   1/1/2017   0   15   30   15
1111   3   1/1/2017   1   30   30   0
1111   3   1/1/2017   2   60   0   0
1111   3   1/1/2017   3   10   0   50
1111   3   1/1/2017   4   0   0   60
1111   4   1/1/2017   0   15   30   15
1111   4   1/1/2017   1   30   30   0
1111   4   1/1/2017   2   60   0   0
1111   4   1/1/2017   3   10   0   50
1111   4   1/1/2017   4   0   0   60
2222   3   1/1/2017   0   15   30   15
2222   3   1/1/2017   1   30   30   0
2222   3   1/1/2017   2   60   0   0
2222   3   1/1/2017   3   10   0   50
2222   3   1/1/2017   4   0   0   60
```

which includes data for days/hours that status has not been changed (like 4 am).
It also need to be a 24 hours table, meaning that each user will have 48 rows per day (2 channels X 24 hours a day).

How can I do it using an Oracle SQL query/ies (as simple as possible)?
+ if can, it need to run fast because I have thousands of rows per a single user and thousands of users..

Thanks,
E

Comment: What have you tried? An hint: if you need to pivot, [pivot](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1) may be a good starting point

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. If the answer you already have doesn't fully answer your question please **edit that post** to provide additional details and clarification.

Comment: It looks the same, but with an addition of 2 more columns that makes the solution more complicated.