# select the unique values in a column to be filed name

Tags: sql, json, oracle, distinct

Table A contains 3 columns as Year, shop and sales.

**Table A**

```
Year Shop   Sales
2015 Shop-A 100
2015 Shop-B 200
2015 Shop-C 300
2016 Shop-A 100
2016 Shop-A 100
2016 Shop-A 100
2017 Shop-A 100
...
```

Is it possible to transfer the format in to this format?

```
Year Shop-A Shop-B Shop-C ...
2015 100     200   300
2016 100     100   100
```

Which Shop A,B,C... are the distinct values of column Shop.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Google "pivot query SQL" to see how to do this.

Comment: Check this. This is what you are looking for.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945504/oracle-sql-developer-how-to-transpose-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a "pivot" as described here: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php.

Here is a query that might work for your example:

```
create table TableA(
    Year int,
    Shop varchar2(100),
    Sales int
    );

delete from TableA;
insert into TableA(Year,Shop,Sales) values(2015,'Shop-A',100);
insert into TableA(Year,Shop,Sales) values(2015,'Shop-B',200);
insert into TableA(Year,Shop,Sales) values(2015,'Shop-C',300);
insert into TableA(Year,Shop,Sales) values(2016,'Shop-A',100);
insert into TableA(Year,Shop,Sales) values(2016,'Shop-B',100);
insert into TableA(Year,Shop,Sales) values(2016,'Shop-C',100);
insert into TableA(Year,Shop,Sales) values(2017,'Shop-A',100);  

/* Show the table as is before pivot*/
select * 
from TableA;

/* The pivoted data. Note that liberties were taken to correct the 2016 - ShopA sales data. */
select *
from
(
    select 
        year,
        sales,
            shop
    from TableA
)
pivot
(
    max(sales)
    for shop in('Shop-A','Shop-B','Shop-C')
)
order by year;
```

I setup the above example in a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc9b7/10) and it returns what was expected.

Note that there's a drawback to the PIVOT clause in that the values listed in the FOR clause are static in the query. The only way to get around this is to use dynamic SQL to build the PIVOT query so that the columns are dynamically added to the query and execute the constructed query string accordingly.