# Get all of the columns name and fetch them into one row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, listagg

So, i know i can select COLUMN names with the query:

```
SELECT column_name FROM ALL_TAB_COLS WHERE table_name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'
```

It's working fine, if i use `rownum = 1`...

```
OUTPUT: sz.price
```

I have to use it, because it's a query in EAS(Enterprise software). If i dont use it -> `subquery returns more than one row`

How can i get all the columns name which are in `MY_TABLE_NAME` fetch into one row ?

```
expected OUTPUT: sz.price, sz.column2, sz.column3, ....
```

Version: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL Developer: How to transpose rows to columns using PIVOT function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945504/oracle-sql-developer-how-to-transpose-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `listagg`

```
select listagg(column_name, ',' )  within group (order by column_name) as "columns"
  from all_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME';
```

Comment: initially you were missing where condition!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh yeah, being fast and tedious :)

Comment: This worked for me to build a query of a huge table without having to type!

Comment: Nice @Marinaio , good luck!

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
select listagg(col_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col_name)from(SELECT column_name  
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS WHERE table_name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME');
```

Comment: Sub-query is not needed